# How to change virtuemart cart values?

Tags: plugin, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 2.5 version. And I am using Virtuemart component for my website.

I have to check that if user is a VIP user then, deduct 10% amount from default virtuemart cart prices.

How can I do this ?

---

Should I develop virtuemart plugin for this purpose?
I know core file hacking is not better technique to change cart values.

I have some business logic to check that if user is vip or not.

If I have to develop plugin for virtuemart (for this purpose) then how can I do this?
I have no idea about plugin development on virtuemart, documentation of virtuemart is very poor also :(

I searched a lot but I did not find anything on google too :(

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any separate extension to achieve this. Just use bulit-in VM Shopper Groups, create one called VIP, and in each product Add new price for VIP shopper group which is 10% lower.

Comment: But how can i check if logged in user is VIP or not ?

Comment: Virtuemart takes care of that. All prices will be automatically adjusted to reflect active shopper group of logged in user, if you created them of course... 
In the case you just need to code it, check this VM Forum post http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=118513.0